# Current leaks while charging. Is the device defective?

Tags: charging, 8.0-oreo, moto-x4, 9.0-pie

During charging(first charge), there is a vibration sense(on my fingers) with my moto x4's metallic sides. Is this shows that the device is defective? What may be the reason?

Comment: Sounds like leaked current. Try another charger / wall socket?

Comment: earthing must not be there considering that particular socket.

Comment: It's with device's original charger(Don't have another c type).  I will try with other wall socket. If this occur again, what may be the issue? Earthing or with device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue: Tingly feeling on hands while touching metallic parts of device.

Test1: Firstly noticed at home during charging. Tried different sockets. [tingly feeling]

Test2: charged using usb with a laptop. [Worked Normal]

Test3: Connected at Office with UPS. [tingly feeling]

I have googled this, and everybody told it was normal(due to no earth pin for charger) and found one comment that, **some chargers have capability of removing leak current, while they are connected in right manner**. Then, I tried with plugging the pins in right order(its written Turbocharger on adapter which should be faced up ) the issue is solved.